# Create database table using QtSQL without executing a query

Tags: mysql, qt

Is it possible to create a table using the QtSql api without executing a query, for example I don't want to do this

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("create table person (id int primary key, "
           "firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20))");
```

Is it possible using qvariants, rather than SQL types
i.e is there an alternative way of adding/ specifying the columns  and data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [QPersistent](https://github.com/Kampfgnom/QPersistence), its a wrapper that convert Qt Object in to SQL tables, the you can manage the database directly by modifying your Qt Objects.

Comment: Thanks mate, looks interesting